# PostgreSQL: how to validate JSON fields?

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to use JSON type instead of table. For example:
CREATE TABLE xds (
id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
info json NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO xds (info)
VALUES('{ "customer": "Lily Bosch",  "type": ["sales","marketing","office"]}'),
('{ "customer": "Josh William","type": ["sales", "office"]}'),
('{ "customer": "Mary Clark",  "type": ["management","startup"]}');
But I'd like to validate  "type" , its values should be  from other table . I can do validation in triggers (I, U) but how to do it?

Comment: This is exactly why what you are trying to do is a bad idea.

Comment: Don't put things on which you need a foreign key reference inside a JSON value.

Comment: I agreed it is bad idea, but it is fast solution for client app developer to create a demo, later I'll need to re-do it in normal way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreeing with the above comment of Mike,what you are trying to do is a bad idea cause you'll have to go extra lengths to do that. If you really want to go with JSON then here is the possible method:

A trigger function and a check constraint can be made. Make a reference table first with appropriate "type" values:

```
CREATE TABLE valid_types (
    type_value text PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO valid_types (type_value) VALUES ('sales'), ('marketing'), ('office'), ('management'), ('startup');
```

Create a trigger function that then verifies the values for the JSON "type" parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_json_type()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.info->'type' IS NOT NULL THEN
        IF NOT (SELECT jsonb_agg(type_value) FROM valid_types) @> (NEW.info->'type')::jsonb THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid "type" value in JSON';
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Create a trigger on the table to invoke the trigger function, and then:

```
CREATE TRIGGER json_type_validation
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON xds
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION validate_json_type();
```

This configuration makes sure that the "type" entries in the "xds" table's JSON column are verified against the "valid_types" reference table, throwing an exception if any value is missing.

For further guidance you can also refer to this [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html). I hope this helps.

Comment: Also you'll need a trigger that cascades (or prevents) updates and deletes in `valid_types`